# Writing a simple bash script encounters string problems

Tags: bash

Since I'm currently trying to write a script file, I'm running into some issues.
This code can be executed correctly.

```
#!/bin/bash

path=$1
files=$(ls $path)
for filename in ${files};
do
   table=$(pwd)
   filePath="${table}/${path}${filename}"
   echo ${filePath}
done
```

But after I added the following python command, the script showed that there was a problem at `path=$1`. I am not sure how the problem occurred and how to modify it.

```
#!/bin/bash

path=$1
files=$(ls $path)
for filename in ${files};
do
   table=$(pwd)
   filePath="${table}/${path}${filename}"
   echo ${filePath}
   python analysisData.sh ${filePath} 4 1024
done
```

Comment: don't run a bash script with a python interpreter

Comment: _the script showed that there was a problem_ is not exactly what I would call a helpful problem description.

Comment: @jhnc why not?...

Comment: @GillesQuénot for the same reason you don't feed sed scripts into `awk`, or javascript into `php`

Comment: @GillesQuénot `bash -c 'python <( echo path=\$1 )'`

Comment: I don't agree. I pass shell to JavaScript [there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/742212/12574). You just need to know what you are doing.

Comment: @GillesQuénot no, you created a shell script that passed a javascript program to node (`<script.js node`);  you did not try to execute a shell script with node (`node script.sh`)

Comment: No waaaay, I just figured what you means :D OK, makes no sense at all!

Answer (score 3):

##### In correct bash:

First:

```
chmod +x analysisData.sh
```

Then:

```
#!/bin/bash

path=$1

for filename in "$PWD/$path"/*; do
   ./analysisData.sh "$filename" 4 1024
done
```

**DO NOT USE `ls`** output for anything. `ls` is a tool for interactively looking at directory metadata. Any attempts at parsing `ls` output with code are broken. Globs are much more simple AND correct: `for file in *.txt`. Read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Hello, thanks very much for your answer, but it seems that I still have the same error when I run this script(SyntaxError: invalid syntax in line 3). Specifically, the $1 position, I used the relative position of my target file.

Comment: Edited my post, try again

Answer (score 1):

Your added code is:

```
   python analysisData.sh ${filePath} 4 1024
```

If `analysisData.sh` is a bash script, it makes no sense to run it with python.

If that script contains a line `path=$1` it will provoke exactly the error message you mention in your comment on @GillesQuénot's answer:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ (echo '#!/bin/bash'; echo; echo 'path=$1') > test.sh
$ python test.sh /a/b/c 4 1024
  File "/tmp/test.sh", line 3
    path=$1
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
$
```

Comment: Good catch =) passed under the radar